# Cosmos DB Stored procedure did not execute

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Cosmos DB. I was trying to execute a stored procedure which simply fetch all the documents based on id and update one property of each documents. While executing it failed to execute.

What's wrong with this Stored Procedure?

```cs
string database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"];
string collection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["collection"];
client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);

DocumentCollection obj = await DocumentClientHelper.GetOrCreateCollectionAsync(client, database, collection);
string scriptFileName = @"E:\Satyaray\NoSql\NosqlDemoConsole\NosqlDemoConsole\Updatevalue.js";
string scriptId = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(scriptFileName);

var sproc = new StoredProcedure {
   Id = scriptId,
   Body = File.ReadAllText(scriptFileName)
};

await DocumentClientHelper.TryDeleteStoredProcedure(client, obj, sproc.Id);

sproc = await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(obj.SelfLink, sproc);

var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync < string > (sproc.SelfLink, new RequestOptions {
PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("XMS-0001")
}, "XMS-001-FE24C");
```

#### Stored procedure

```
function simple(id) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

    getAndUpdatedata();

    function getAndUpdatedata() {

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM root r where r.id=' + id,
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (var i = 0; i < feed.length; i++) {
                var metaDoc = feed[i];

                metaDoc.readingTime = new Date();
                var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(metaDoc._self, metaDoc, function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                });
                if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("The call replaceDocument(metaDoc) returned false.");
            }


        });

        if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("The call queryDocuments for metaDoc returned false.");
    }
}
```

#### Error Message

```
Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":32,\"end\":35},\"code\":\"SC2001\",\"message\":\"Identifier 'XMS' could not be resolved.\"},{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":40,\"end\":45},\"code\":\"SC2001\",\"message\":\"Identifier 'FE24C' could not be resolved.\"}]}\r\nStack trace: Error: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":32,\"end\":35},\"code\":\"SC2001\",\"message\":\"Identifier 'XMS' could not be resolved.\"},{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{"]}
ActivityId: 62e49cf4-1259-4d36-a196-7f752ceeba53, Request URI: /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer22/partitions/a4cb4962-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.108.4, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.20.2 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0
```

Comment: Is that all your code? I tried to validate your JS code and it would fail... have it checked here for example https://codebeautify.org/jsvalidate . Or use any linter to validate it.

Comment: @MaximeRouiller yes.

Comment: Your JS code doesn't validate as valid Javascript. Are you missing code/closing brackets?

Comment: @SaTyA Any updates now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `console.log` to print your sql and I found it looks like :

```
SELECT * FROM root r where r.id= XMS-001-FE24C
```

Actually , it should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM root r where r.id= 'XMS-001-FE24C'
```

So, please modify the SQL in your Stored Procedure a little bit and it works fine:

```
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    "SELECT * FROM r where r.id = '" + id + "'",
    ......
```

BTW, `id` is user-defined unique name of the resource which is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#system-vs-user-defined-resources). So i think the result of your sql should contain only one piece of data , no need to loop the `feed` array.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks it works for me .if the collection has PartitionKey then it Compulsory to use PartitionKey in RequestOptions in Stored Procedure ? is there any way to use FeedOptions property EnableCrossPartitionQuery =true in Stored Procedure  @JayGong